# Exporting a 3d model created in sketchup for use in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, sketchup

I have a problem using opengl on android to draw a simple rectangle.
This is what I have done.

I drew a simple rectangle with sketchup.  I exported the result using
a 3d-model collada .dae file.  I then copied the vertices data from
the .dae (xml) file and put in an array.  I copied the array in native
format to a float buffer.  I then drew the triangles using stripe
mode.  The result is nearly a rectangle.  It is missing a triangle on
each surface.

Here is the relevant portion of code and the result.

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
    // Enable color tracking
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    for (int i=0; i<108/4; i=i+4) {
        myDrawColor(gl,i);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,i,4);// mode, first, count
    }
}
```

the result is shown here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhnNz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code working.  There were three problems.

1. DrawArrays works forward through the vertex array.  ie. you draw one element from the array at a time and then go to the next.  You can not hop back and forth thru it.
2. Using the offset list in the .xml file I created an array that I could use with glDrawElements where it hops around in the vertices list.
3. You need to use unsigned short of the offset.  I was using an integer and fixed which did not work.

Here is the resulting code that works.  The problem was mine. Not the .xml file produced from sketchup.

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorsBuffer);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); 
// Enable color tracking 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, myoffsets.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndicesBuffer); // mode, count, type, indices
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your vertexes in the wrong order in your vertex list (which could be the fault of the export). This is what I got from my quads when i had the vertices in the wrong places. You will want to build them counter-clockwise from the outside. It could also be that triangle strip is causing issues with your vertices, for an application this simple you could try GL_QUADS.